# CSS: Flex item not growing with content in chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been facing this issue for hours and i haven't find a fix for it, not even with the answers found on other questions. It seems like the flex items are not well positioned in `google-chrome` as they are in `mozilla firefox`.

I am making a list of tables to display as report of dates, each item contains a table that display the activities done in that particular date, and all of these items are displayed with `flex` in `column` direction to make put the title date above the table, also because the table must be in the center of the item.

Everything works fine until the second item is put, the second item takes part of the space that the first item is taking and that's because the item is not getting the height it should, which should grow with the content.

An example of the `HTML` structure goes like this:

```
<div id="box-2">
    <!-- repeat(Reports) -->
    <div class="box-item">
        <h5>{Reports[].date}</h5>

        <div class="box-table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <!-- Headers -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- data -->
                    </tr>
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and `CSS` goes like this:

```
#box-2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.box-item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box-item > .box-table{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Again, when the second item box is placed, it is displaying over the first item at some point and it happens to the rest of other items after the first, this doesn't happen in firefox but i still want to know how to fix this.

I have created a plunk for this so i could show the code that resemblances more with the orignal [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/s8wRmNepEH54bZtN9J5b?p=info)

Comment: Please create a code snippet for which we could try on

Comment: @Swellar the snipped is in a plunk link https://plnkr.co/edit/s8wRmNepEH54bZtN9J5b?p=info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flex-shrink` defaults to `1`, which means that a flex item is allowed to shrink to fit its flex container, and that is what happens here.

Remove all but i.e. 2 `.box-item`'s, so they fit within its parent, and you'll see it render properly.

Add `flex-shrink: 0;` to `.box-item` and it will work.

[Updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UJviDjTT9PL7af1iTFgY?p=preview)

Stack snippet

```css
body, html{
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: arial;
}

hr{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 8px;
}

#main-content{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 8px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box-2{
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.box-item{
  flex-shrink: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.box-item > h5{
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.box-item > .box-table{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 60%;
}
.box-item > .box-table table{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.box-table table > thead{
 background: #54585F;
 color: #FFF;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.box-table table > tbody > tr:not(:last-of-type){
 border-width: 0 0 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
 <div id="main-content">
  <div id="box-1">
   <h2>Box header</h2>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="box-2">
   <div class="box-item">
    <h5>Box item</h5>
    
    <div class="box-table">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>header #1</th>
        <th>header #2</th>
        <th>header #3</th>
        <th>header #4</th>
        <th>header #5</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-item">
    <h5>Box item</h5>
    
    <div class="box-table">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>header #1</th>
        <th>header #2</th>
        <th>header #3</th>
        <th>header #4</th>
        <th>header #5</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-item">
    <h5>Box item</h5>
    
    <div class="box-table">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>header #1</th>
        <th>header #2</th>
        <th>header #3</th>
        <th>header #4</th>
        <th>header #5</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-item">
    <h5>Box item</h5>
    
    <div class="box-table">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>header #1</th>
        <th>header #2</th>
        <th>header #3</th>
        <th>header #4</th>
        <th>header #5</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-item">
    <h5>Box item</h5>
    
    <div class="box-table">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>header #1</th>
        <th>header #2</th>
        <th>header #3</th>
        <th>header #4</th>
        <th>header #5</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-item">
    <h5>Box item</h5>
    
    <div class="box-table">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>header #1</th>
        <th>header #2</th>
        <th>header #3</th>
        <th>header #4</th>
        <th>header #5</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-item">
    <h5>Box item</h5>
    
    <div class="box-table">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>header #1</th>
        <th>header #2</th>
        <th>header #3</th>
        <th>header #4</th>
        <th>header #5</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
        <td><div>data</div></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works. Would you mind to explain why this happens?, why this has different results on both browsers?

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, i will set this as the answer.. although i still would like to know why the behavior is different between `firefox` and `chrome` when `flex-shrink` is not set, if you don't know then that's fine

Comment: @nosthertus The reason why they behave different is because the browser manufacturer interpret how to implement a certain feature different. In this case webkit browser does it one way (i.e. Chrome/Opera) and FireFox/Edge in another....and we call it _bugs_ :) ... and the big question is always: "Which one got it right?"